# Is there ever a good reason to use labeled Statements?

Tags: javascript

In website [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) say that:

**Avoid using labels**

> Labels are not very commonly used in JavaScript since they make programs harder to read and understand. As much as possible, avoid using labels and, depending on the cases, prefer calling functions or throwing an error.

Is there ever a good reason to use labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you share contains a use case which normally consider as reason.

```
var allPass = true;
var i, j;

top:
for (i = 0; items.length; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < tests.length; i++)
    if (!tests[j].pass(items[i])){
      allPass = false;
      break top;
    }
```

basically, you do not need to use extra flag variable to break out of nested loop early.

if you would like to see it in action, run follows in your browser's JavaScript console.

```
top:
for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    console.log("i" + i);
    for (j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
        console.log("j" + j);
        break top;
    }
}
```

expected output will be:

```
i0
j0
```

Comment: It could be argued that the better code would put these nested for loops into a separate function where a `return` could be used.

Comment: it depends, if it is a process of some matrix data structure (e.g. image), it is much readable to have nested loop than separate function.